# Python ctypes Passing a Pointer and getting null pointer access

Tags: python, ctypes, hardware

I'm using Python and ctypes to use a .dll supplied by a company for the use with a load cell amplifier. I manage to get a reading with their software, but I can't get my Python code to work.
The company is [ME-MessSysteme](https://www.me-systeme.de/produkte/software/megsv/ba-megsv.pdf), and the amplifier is the GSV-2 ([Manual Here](https://www.me-systeme.de/produkte/software/megsv/ba-megsv.pdf)).

The company's description of the function:

> > C: int GSVread ( int no, double *ad )

Taken from [here](https://www.me-systeme.de/produkte/software/megsv/ba-megsv.pdf), page 44. Sorry, but the guide is in German.

I'm getting a response from the amplifier after the activate function, but when I use the GSVread function, I can't get the result. I tried to pass a pointer to a double variable as I understand it returns the value to it. When I try to access the contents I get a "ValueError: NULL pointer access".

```
import ctypes
ret = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)()
print(ret)
gsv = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("DLLs_SENSOLYTICS/MEGSV.dll")
print(gsv.GSVactivate(7))
print(gsv.GSVstartTransmit(7))
print(gsv.GSVread(7, ret))
print(ret.contents)
```

7 indicating the COM port number.

Thank you all in advance!

****UPDATE*****
Following on Dan's answer, the code that works is below:

```
    d = ctypes.c_double()
    ret = ctypes.byref(d)

    gsv = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("DLLs_SENSOLYTICS/MEGSV.dll")
    print(gsv.GSVactivate(7, ctypes.c_long(256)))
    gsv.GSVflushBuffer(7)
    print(gsv.GSVstartTransmit(7))
    time.sleep(1)
    gsv.GSVread(7, ret)
    print(d)
```

Comment: Typically, just do `d = ctypes.c_double()`, then `gsv.GSVread(7,ctypes.byref(d))`.  That passes the address of `d` to the function, and `d.value` will be the result when the function returns.  It's also a good habit to explicitly define `.argtypes` and `.restype` for each function so ctypes can perform type checking and properly marshal the arguments to the C function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create two objects one the double and the other the pointer to the double:

```
>>> d = ctypes.c_double()
>>> ret = ctypes.pointer(d)
>>> ret.contents
c_double(0.0)
```

This can also be written as:

```
ret = ctypes.pointer(ctypes.c_double())
```

Which is oddly similar to:

```
ret = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)()
```

The documentation states that `ctypes.byref` is a faster `ctypes.pointer` that doesn't actually allocate a real `ctypes.pointer` object so it can only be used to be be passed to a reference as an argument to a C function.

To use it one has to keep a direct reference to the double to be able to access the result as `ctypes.byref` objects do not have a contents property.

```
d = ctypes.c_double()
ret = ctypes.byref(d)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This indeed works, and I would like to add that it also took to add a waiting period. The new code is updated in the question.